# Один или раз?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Когда мы что-то считаем, то чаще всего выходит так, как в известной всем с детства считалке: *"Раз, два, три, четыре, пять. Я иду искать"*. Но при этом первая цифра - это все-таки единица, значит, один. Выходит, что "раз, два, три..." - говорить неграмотно? А в армии вообще командуют "ать-два, левой!"
Хотелось бы знать, откуда взялся этот "раз" и правильно ли вообще считать "раз, два, три..."? А если да, то в каких случаях уместно считать "один, два, три...", а в каких - "раз..."?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Один, два, три - так обычно считают предметы или ведут математический счет. Раз, два, три - такой счет удобен для обозначения действий.

Дело в том, что РАЗ - многозначное слово: а) числительное один; б) существительное, обозначающее кратность действия или место действия в ряду подобных: один раз, первый раз.

А в считалочках слово "раз" удобно для произношения.

Answer (score -1):

Это древнеславянские образы которые у многих на подсознании. Кому интересно может забить в поисковике " **Образы Буквицы**"
Скорей всего АЗ-цибровое значение - 1
**Рѣци** – речь, изречение, течение; упорядочивание и разграничение нашего пространства.
**Азъ** – то, с чего все начинается; исток, начало, изначалье; Бог, создающий на Земле; единый, единство; человек; я.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]