# Откуда взялось слово "раз" в "раз, два ,три .." и почему оно доминирует в устной речи над естественным "один, два, три.."?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

Дочь осваивает речь. Научилась считать до трёх: "один, два, три". А я ловлю себя на том, что мне хочется считать "раз, два, три". Неважно предметы или действия. Поразмышляв, пришел к мнению, что дочь считает правильней, потому что она перебирает числительные, а я на первое место ставлю существительное не имеющее прямого отношения к числу 1. С таким же успехом можно считать так: "штука, два, три".
Любопытно, что вопрос на сайте уже поднимался, но принятые ответы противоречат друг другу.

["Один" или "раз"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2887/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7)

[Один или раз?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/38208/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 5):

Один раз, два раза, три раза  - здесь "раз" выступает в качестве существительного, но обозначает кратность действия. Слово *раз* возникло в 10-11 вв  от общеславянского **разъ** - раз, удар, случай, от **разити**, как бы получается удар, два удара, три удара. Например, три удара колокола.

Числовой ряд **один, два, три.**.. имеет математическое значение, а также  может использоваться для счета любых  предметов или действий. Эти числительные общеславянского или индоевропейского происхождения: one, two, three... Кстати, существует предположение, что раньше ряд начинался с числа *два*, так как понятие **один** было слишком абстрактным для того времени.

Так или иначе, но в русском языке (преимущественно в устной речи) слово  *раз (удар)* может замещать числительное **один**.

Отметим, что в английском языке *раз* при счете действий  соответствует слову ***time***, а оно к числительным не имеет отношения: три раза -  three times.

Comment: Эх раз да ещё раз да ещё **много много раз**. (Не разов)

Answer (score 2):

**"Раз"** — это "**мера**". Нет, не мера из "эталонов стандарта", а просто мера, и не суть важно чего, но подсчёт количества ме́рок вёлся в "**раза́х**". Будь то мера жидкости, расстояний или рассыпного (не штучного) товара.
Мера — это и ведро, и таз, и ковш, и мешок, и цистерна. Для математика мера — это переменная, например "икс": **20x = 20раз = 20мер**. Подставляй нужное значение *(километр, миля, ло́коть, аршин, дюйм, четверть, неделя, месяц, год, цикл)* и вычисляй результат.

Продолжительность какого-либо цикла — она ведь тоже ой какая разная бывает, но количество этих циклов можно сосчитать и в раза́х.
Кто не помнит советский мультик, где удав, измеряемый в попугаях, вдруг оказался в **разы́** "длиннее", чем он же, измеряемый в мартышках?
Или:  *Столько да ещё пол-столько да ещё четверть-столько - это сколько?*  (семь четверте́й). В этом случае слово "че́тверть" играет также роль переменной (четверть круга, четверть пути и т. д.).
Если я напишу **1x**, то мне разрешат не писать единицу, а если я напишу **1 раз**, но без единицы? Логично предположить, что эта вольность не должна считаться ошибкой.

### [Кириллическая система счисления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

> Большинство букв древнерусского алфавита имели числовое соответствие.
>   Так, буква «**Аз**» означала «один», «**Ве́ди**» — «два»…

Я не утверждаю, что происхождение слова "раз" является потомком древнего алфавитно-числительного "Аз", но ой как похоже...
*Отсыпь мне две-на-дцать р**Аз** по мерке*  или  *Наме́дни сверстаю дважды десять р**Аз** по лету да ещё два лета* (два-дцать два года).

А давно ли мы или "они" перешли на общепризнанные эталоны между народами, да и перешли ли полностью?
Как там:
*[Единое счисление мер и весов](http://www.krugosvet.ru/enc/nauka_i_tehnika/matematika/TSIFRI_I_SISTEMI_SCHISLENIYA.html?page=0,6)*. Вот только не стоит ждать от повсеместной стандартизации дополнительных чудес. Тем более в языках. Полностью стандартизированный и более не развивающийся язык — уже мёртвый язык.

> [Во времена Великой французской революции](http://www.slovopedia.com/14/214/1020851.html), на заседаниях Революционной
>   комиссии по весам и мерам, высказывались мнения о введении
>   двенадцатиричных систем мер и весов, но окончательное решение
>   склонилось в пользу унификации мер и весов на основе десятичной
>   системы счисления.

Answer (score 0):

Счётный ряд задаётся комбинацией из 12 простых чисел в количественной и порядковой разновидности — от 1 до 10, 100 и 1000.

И хотя счётная последовательность обладает свойствами связного текста, где каждому слову дано строго определённое место, и даже синонимические замены невозможны, включение в неё слова ***раз*** как следствие инновации количественного счёта в разговорной речи — есть историческая реальность.

В количественных же выражениях из предметно-вещного мира это недопустимо (*Он взял одно яблоко* vs. * *Он взял раз яблоко*).

Источник: «Историческая грамматика русского языка» О.Ф. Жолобова 2006 г.

Доминирования слова *раз* никем не отмечается. На запрос «откуда взялось» отвечает Этимологический онлайн-словарь РЯ Шанского Н. М.:

> Общеслав. Производное от *разить*. *Раз* исходно «удар».

А также от *разимати* — раделять. Первоначально связано чередованием гласных с глаголом *ре́зать*. Родственно  существительным *полоса*, *черта*.

Comment: *Он взял яблоко раз* или *Он взял яблоко разик (разок, разевича)*

Comment: Хотя нет. Это другой смысл  = *Он взял яблоко единожды*